# How perform a breakpoint only when I'm debugging in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, forms, debugging

I want perform a breakpoint in code only when I'm working in the code directly. I tried this solution, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
<Conditional("DEBUG")>
Public Sub Breakpoint()
    #If DEBUG Then
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
    #End If
End Sub
```

How do I identify the problem?

Comment: Why not just set a breakpoint in Visual Studio with `F9`?

Comment: My idea it's trying to avoid to throw a exception when I'm debugging my code. But throw the exception if the application is running since the computer of any user.

Comment: I use a lot the breakpoint (with F9), but sometime I clear all breakpoints since the code. It's a manner to don't erase some breakpoints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
If System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached Then
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
End If
```